# Jmeter response is having HTML code along with Java scripts. How to get complete HTML view source(after java script execution) through Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to do performance testing of Web application. while doing this, i am sending one http get request which is giving response having in html format(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="UIServiceContext "  >
<head>.....)
```

this html is having lot of java script function and asd. But my need is to get
complete html view source after java scripts execution through jmeter which i am getting through web application while working on browser( through fiddler with same get request) . please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see full rendered response with images, styles, etc. try switching to `Browser` mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener:

[image]

If your use case is different and you need to get response data for i.e. [correlation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) be aware that according to [JMeter project main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

so if the data you're "missing" originates from a JavaScript-driven [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) call - JMeter will not execute this call automatically, you will have to manually create the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to mimic this particular request and the value(s) you're looking for will be in the response of the request.

If your application assumes more than 1 AJAX call - consider putting them under the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md) as real browsers execute AJAX calls asynchronously and [JMeter should act as close to real browser as it is possible](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).